# shell bash global replace on a file

Tags: bash, shell, replace, sed, grep

I am wondering how I can do a global replace on a file,

basically, I have a file containing several properties and I loop through this file creating an array to store each propety value. the property value is stored in the format:

```
$key=$value
```

So what I am trying to do is to loop through my array of property and replace all key's within a file with the corresponding value. The keys are highlighted by use if the following format:

```
[#$key#]
```

So what I am trying to do is to loop through the array and for each element, do a global replace within my file by cat'ing to a temporary file using sed to replace all instances of the key (inside the [##] tags) with the value. I will then cat the temp file back to the original.

However, what I have is not replacing all elements, i.e. not a global replace.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for x in "${props[@]}"
do
    key='echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 1
    value='echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 2


    # global replace on the $MY_FILE
    cat $MY_FILE | sed s/'\[#$key#\]'/$value/ > $TEMP_MY_FILE
    cat $TEMP_MY_FILE > $MY_FILE

done
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Say `sed s/'\[#$key#\]'/$value/g` instead for _global replace_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for x in "${props[@]}"
do
    key='echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 1
    value='echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 2

    # global replace on the $MY_FILE
    sed -i "s/#$key#/$value/g" $MY_FILE
done
```

The `sed -i` do the modifications directly in the file, without temp files

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the post of **h3nr1x** we can try this:

```
SED_CMD=""
for x in "${props[@]}"
do
    key=$(echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
    value=$(echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 2)
    SED_CMD="${SED_CMD}s/#$key#/$value/g
"
done
# global replace on the $MY_FILE
sed -i "$SED_CMD" $MY_FILE
```

The **sed** command will be executed one time only directly on the file.
**NOTE**: on the statement which append value to SED_CMD variable, the closing double quote must be at beginning of next line in order to insert new line after each **sed** command.